# VPC endpoint creation fails with InvalidServiceName with aws-java-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, aws-private-link, aws-networking

I am trying to create a VPC endpoint using aws-java-sdk "com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateVpcEndpointRequest" API. This fails with the below issue. This is being created in a private subnet.

```
error": "com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: The Vpc Endpoint Service 'com.amazonaws.vpce.us-west-2.vpce-svc-***' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidServiceName; Request ID: ***; Proxy: null)"
```

The VPCE-svc is added with the allowed principal and configured to accept the connection requests automatically.

**Please note that we are able to create the VPC endpoint against the same vpce-svc manually.
The code works fine, able to successfully create vpc endpoints for different accounts/vpc-svc/vpc/subnet. The issue is limited to one setup**

Any pointer to debug this is greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

Update: code snippet

```html
    createVpcEndpointRequest request = new CreateVpcEndpointRequest()
            .withPrivateDnsEnabled(privateDns)
            .withSecurityGroupIds(Collections.singleton(securityGroupId))
            // VPCE Service
            .withVpcEndpointType(VpcEndpointType.Interface.toString())
            .withServiceName(privatelinkServiceName)
            // Network
            .withVpcId(vpcId)
            .withSubnetIds(subnetIds);
    createVpcEndpointResult = ec2Client.createVpcEndpoint(request);
```

Comment: Could you share the code you are using?

Comment: @palvarez updated the code. Also the code works fine for all the use cases. The issue is limited to one setup